# RVM on EC2 - operation timeout when installing ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, rvm

Im sure this is a simple answer to this problem, though I can't see it at the moment.

Im running RVM on a small EC2 instance. However when running a rvm install 'ruby-version' the console will eventually freeze up and I will get the following response.. Operation timed out.

Any ideas on how to keep this running?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this one

```
#change ssh timeouts
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

#add these settings
ClientAliveInterval 30
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveCountMax 99999

#restart ssh
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```